# Replace word with string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some string and in string i wana to replace 355#00$1 with 7777777 but it's not working... what i m doing wrong please help..

```
<p class="str_content">
you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's and you355#00$1 ne355#00$1ed to find the link of that li355#00$1's anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
prateek
you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's355#00$1 and you need to find the link of that li's355#00$1 anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
prateek
you mean .active355#00$1 class can be any of the 6 li's and you need to find the link of that li's anchor in355#00$1 other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
355#00$1

</p>

<p class="replace">Replace</p>

<script>
$(".replace").on("click",function(e){
    var data=$(".str_content").html();  
    var new_data=data.replace(/'355#00$1'/gi,'7777777');
    $(".str_content").html(new_data);

    alert($(".str_content").html(new_data));

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the issue is with the syntax of the regular expression. You don't need to place it in quotes, and the `$` character needs to be escaped as it has a special meaning in Regex.

Also note that you can provide `html()` with a function to amend the value instead of selecting the element multiple times. It may also be worth using `text()` instead, as you don't appear to have any HTML within the content of the `p` element. Try this:

```js
$(".replace").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".str_content").html(function(i, html) {
   return html.replace(/355#00\$1/g, '7777777');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="str_content">
  you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's and you355#00$1 ne355#00$1ed to find the link of that li355#00$1's anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right? prateek you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's355#00$1 and you
  need to find the link of that li's355#00$1 anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right? prateek you mean .active355#00$1 class can be any of the 6 li's and you need to find the link of that li's anchor in355#00$1 other navs and
  assign .active class to them.Am I right? 355#00$1
</p>

<p class="replace">Replace</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replace like,

```
var new_data=data.replace(/355#00\$1/ig,'7777777');
```

```js
$(".replace").on("click",function(e){
    var data=$(".str_content").html();  
    var new_data=data.replace(/355#00\$1/ig,'7777777');
    $(".str_content").html(new_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="str_content">
you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's and you355#00$1 ne355#00$1ed to find the link of that li355#00$1's anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
prateek
you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's355#00$1 and you need to find the link of that li's355#00$1 anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
prateek
you mean .active355#00$1 class can be any of the 6 li's and you need to find the link of that li's anchor in355#00$1 other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?
355#00$1

</p>

<p class="replace">Replace</p>
```